# How to check if a rotated rectangle is contained in another rotated rectangle?

Tags: extents

I need to check if a rotated rectangle **A** is inside a rotated rectangle **B**. That is, if **B** is completely contained in **A**. I have the following information stored in a rotated rectangle: the four coordinates and its angle.

Is there is an efficient method to do this? I know that the Separating Axis Theorem can check a intersection situation, but is this method still valid to check a containment situation?

Comment: Which software do you need for this check?

Comment: I need check it in C. For this purpose, any library in C or C++ would be ok.

Answer (score 2):

With rectangles, a [point in polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)  algorithm would be quite efficient. If the four corners of polygon A are inside of polygon B, then polygon A is inside polygon B. You have maximum 4 points to check on 4 edges, so this should be fast. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716268/point-in-polygon-algorithm) for an example of point in polygon implementation.

Comment: It seems interesting to me. What do you think to use this algorithm to check if there is an intersection between two rotated rectangles? I mean, if one corner of polygon A is inside of polygon B, then A intersects B. Does it make sense? I saw that in the implementation that you mentioned, it is possible to check if the point is also in the border or a polygon or not. Is it right too?